# Get list of users created 14 days ago Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script to pull the `'CW - OTHER'` attribute.

But What i now need is to tell this command that I only want you to pull those name created:

> 14 "BEFORE".

I tried defining a variable for [`Get-date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7). Not working out at all; keep getting a syntax error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$thedate = get-date -date $(get-date).adddays(-14) -format yyyy-MM-dd
Get-ADUser -Filter { Title -eq 'CW - OTHER' -and whencreated $thedate } -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title `
    | select DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title `
    | Export-CSV "C:\Scripts\Email_Addresses.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$thedate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
Get-ADUser -Filter { Title -eq 'CW - OTHER' -and whencreated -gt $thedate } -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title `
        | select DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title `
        | Export-CSV "C:\Scripts\Email_Addresses.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Issues:
Formatting the date converts the date to a String. You didn't have a Comparison Operator for the second part of your filter.

Comment: I just figured that out. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The OP won't notice this unless you 'ping' with @shawnb23